# Stopping/Starting FTP site in IIS via command prompt error

Tags: windows, batch-file, iis, cmd, appcmd

I use the batch file command:

```
appcmd site stop "name"
```

but when I use it on my FTP site in the IIS, it returns an error:

```
< hresult:800710d8, message:Command execution failed. The object identifier does not represent a valid object. >
```

my batch file works fine for other sites, just this one ftp site is returning that error.

Comment: Which version of IIS?

Comment: Using 7.5. Server is Windows 2008 R2